# Ms access transfertext converting text in excel cvs to Currency

Tags: ms-access, importerror

I am trying to import data from excel csv to MS Access. A column in csv has majority of values like "F0000123". Few Values are "E0000123". While importing this using transfertext to Text column in Access, F0000123 has changed to 123 and E0000123 has been imported as blank with datatype conversion failure. If importing to new blank (no columns defined) table F0000123 importing as $123 and again E0000123 has been imported as blank with datatype conversion failure. Please help why value starting with F have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Link the csv file as a table. Then create a query to read and convert (purify) the data.

Use this query as source for further processing of the date like appending data to other tables.